# Symfony install behind company firewall

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, firewall

My company is blocking access to github (I suppose to prevent source code from leaking). However, a dependency of symfony is "**symfony/flex (v1.5.3)**", and must connect to github.com to install successfully.

When I run composer install, I get the following message :

```
Installing symfony/flex (v1.5.3): Cloning 59b42aa1d3


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                               
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/flex.git via https, ssh, git protocols, aborting.
```

Is there any way I can't still use symfony withouth the access to github ?

Actually, to install composer dependencies I was able to use my company **artifactory** repositories, but I don't think they have it for symfony flex.

Comment: somebody probably has the rights to configure your artifactory to proxy github packages. if only github is blocked you can also try packagist

Comment: Could you not download the zip and install that way

Comment: @NormanM I searched for symfony flex and didn't found anything on artifactory.

Comment: @RiggsFolly What do you mean ?

Comment: @LéoColetta yes, when it is not there yet - somebody in your company will have the rights to add it